# Special Select Statement. Select all SKU base on its Main SKU

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-select-db

Every one. I have a mySQL table like this:

> ```
> DATA(sku,quantity)
> ABC           55
> ABC_DE005     1
> ABC_DE006     1
> ABC_DE007     1
> ABC_DE008     1
> DEF           30
> DEF_DE56      1
> DEF_DE57      1
> DEF_DE58      1
> DEF_DE59      1
> DEF_DE60      1
> DEF_DE61      1
> XYZ           0
> XYZ_DE565     0
> XYZ_DE566     0
> XYZ_DE567     0
> XYZ_DE568     0
> XYZ_DE569     0
> ```

ABC is the main SKU, ABC_DExx is the sub SKU and the quantity always is 1 or 0.
My question is: 
How can I select all the Sku which have quantity over 20 base on the main SKU?  Or If main SKU have quantity over 20 then main SKU and it sub SKU will be selected.
some thing like

```
     "SELECT * From DATA Where quantity > 20 ..."
```

Below is the final result I want (main SKU (Ex: ABC) and it sub SKU (ex: ABC_DExx) will show up because main SKU ABC is over 20):

> ```
> DATA(sku,quantity)
> ABC           55
> ABC_DE005     1
> ABC_DE006     1
> ABC_DE007     1
> ABC_DE008     1
> DEF           30
> DEF_DE56      1
> DEF_DE57      1
> DEF_DE58      1
> DEF_DE59      1
> DEF_DE60      1
> DEF_DE61      1
> ```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using CONCAT Operator; please find the below code.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/ELA41093)

```
SELECT DATA.sku, DATA.quantity FROM DATA
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE quantity > 20) DATA1 ON
DATA.sku = DATA1.sku OR DATA.sku LIKE CONCAT(DATA1.sku, '%');
```

Output

[image: Output of above query]

Answer (score 0):

you could use ainner join with like and an union

```
select a.* 
from data a 
inner join data b on b. quantity  > 20  
    and a.sku like concat( b.sku , '%' )
union 
select * 
from data
where  quantity  > 20 
order by sku
```

Comment: There has no data b. So your code seems doesn't work

Comment: seems impssibile at least  the union subselect should retunr the row with sku quantity > 0  ..  check better

Answer (score 0):

```
select sku, quantity
  from data
       inner join (select sku from data where quantity > 20) data1
          on data.sku like data1.sku + '%'
```

Comment: I did a try but It show the main SKU only. Is there any way I can show bot main and sub SKU but base on main SKU quantity?